# Draw circle with three colours in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles, draw

I would like to have a circle where the circumference is coloured with three different colours, something like the following but a line and with only three colours:

[image: Like this]

I initially tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [red] (0,0) arc [radius=1, start angle=0, end angle=120];
    \draw [green] (1,0) arc [radius=1, start angle=120, end angle=240];
    \draw [blue] (0,0) arc [radius=1, start angle=240, end angle=360];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

but this does not give the right result, and the arguments of the function are such that it's quite difficult to make what I have in mind.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Please don't post code fragments. Instead put your code into a complete compilable document that people can play with.

Comment: Sorry! Fixed it now, let me know if there's something else to fix.

Comment: What do you have in mind exactly? We know what it isn't, but what is it? What do you mean by a line?

Comment: I actually had no precise idea of what I meant by "line" except for "something thinner than the picture". All of the answers below work well for what I need to do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that an `arc` of radius 1 from one coordinate (call it A) which starts at angle X and ends at angle Y will assume that A is at angle of X on the circumference of a circle with radius 1.

So your first `arc` assumes that `(0,0)` is at zero degrees on the circumference of a circle with radius 1. This means the centre of the circle must be at `(-1,0)`.

But your second `arc` assumes that `(1,0)` is at 120 degrees on the circumference of a circle with radius 1. So the centre must be at `(1.5,{.5*(sqrt(3))}`.

Finally, your third `arc` assumes that `(0,0)` is at 240 degrees on the circumference of a circle with radius 1. So the centre must be at `({cos(60)},{sin(60)})`.

[On the improbable assumption that I've not messed up the geometry at this hour of the night.]

I suggest using polar coordinates instead. Then your `arc`s can start at `(0:1)`, `(120:1)` and `(240:1)` which makes things much simpler.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [red] (0:1) arc [radius=1, start angle=0, end angle=120];
  \draw [green] (120:1) arc [radius=1, start angle=120, end angle=240];
  \draw [blue] (240:1) arc [radius=1, start angle=240, end angle=360];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: joining up <code>arc</code>s]

Comment: +1 for the explanation and for having read the question carefully!

Answer (score 10):

I am posting this code, which is from a deleted answer by Zarko on a related question ([TikZ: Circle with color transition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285996/2693)). It is not my code, so I've made the answer Community Wiki.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[radius=32mm]
\foreach \i [count=\ii from 0] in {red, green, blue}
    \fill[\i] (0,0) -- (\ii*120:32mm)
                    arc[start angle=\ii*120,delta angle=120]
                    -- cycle;
    \fill[white] (0,0) circle (16mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

To add the white space between the parts, you can use `\fill[\i, draw=white, very thick]`.  To make the bars thinner, adjust the  size of white circle in the middle.

Answer (score 5):

*Edit:*

cfr's comment made me read more carefully your question.

Of course, if you need only a line, you may increase the radius of the white internal circle, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
        \foreach \mycolor/\mygrad in {red/0,green/120,blue/240}
            \tkzDrawSector[R,draw=white,fill=\mycolor](O,1)(\mygrad,\mygrad+120);
        \fill[white] (0,0) circle (.95); % <--- here put the value you like
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Original answer:*

You could also use `tkz-euclide` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
        \foreach \mycolor/\mygrad in {red/0,green/120,blue/240}
            \tkzDrawSector[R,draw=white,fill=\mycolor](O,1)(\mygrad,\mygrad+120);
        \fill[white] (0,0) circle (.5);  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The gaps look smooth and much better than no gaps IMO. Also there are gaps in the original image specified.

Comment: @MCMastery Thank you! Indeed, I put the gaps because they were in the original image. However, you may also easily avoid them, it's enough to write `\draw=mycolor` instead of `\draw=white`.

Comment: @MCMastery The original image misled us a bit, actually the OP asked for a line only...