# Filling part of a circle with a gradient following the circle-curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, gradient

I want to fill the lower part of the circle (225° - 315°) with a gradient that is oriented to the curve of the circle. The whole sides at 225° and 315° should be the beginning of the colors. Now it's oriented to the tips on both sides.

```
  \fill[lightgray] (0,0) -- (90:5) arc (90:225:5) -- cycle; 
  
  \fill[left color=lightgray, right color=white] (0,0) -- (225:5) arc (225:315:5) -- cycle;
```

[image: circle_screenshot]

My idea is, that the gradient should orientate on a path like the one below (roughly drawn over the image), but i really do not know how to make that happen. I would highly appreciate any tipps or links to information that would be usefull to me.

[I looked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141378/path-following-color-gradient-in-tikz), but it does not seem to fit my problem.]

[image]

---

Full code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}

\usepackage{tikz}

%\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows,trees,shapes,through, positioning, backgrounds, fadings}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=15mm,
 top=20mm,
 right=15mm
 }

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{XXX}}
\lhead{XXX}
%\rfoot{Page \thepage}



\begin{document}

\hfill

\centering

{\huge\textbf{mentales Lexikon\\}}

\bigskip

\textbf{Übung zur Elaboration/Speicherung von Wörtern}\\\smallskip von XXX

\bigskip
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{tikzpicture}[framed, text centered]
  
  \coordinate (1) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (2) at (0,5);

  \fill[lightgray] (0,0) -- (90:5) arc (90:225:5) -- cycle; 
  
  \fill[left color=lightgray, right color=white] (0,0) -- (225:5) arc (225:315:5) -- cycle; 


  %fill=left!30!white

  \draw[black] (0:5)  -- (1);
  \draw[black] (45:5) -- (1);
  \draw[white] (90:5) -- (1);
  \draw[white] (135:5) -- (1);
  \draw[white] (180:5) -- (1);
  \draw[white] (225:5) -- (1);
  \draw[white] (270:5) -- (1);
  \draw[black] (315:5) -- (1);

  \node [draw, circle through=(2), very thick] at (1) {};

  \node [align=center] (episodisch) at (22.5:3.3) {episodische\\Informationen};
  \node [align=center,draw, fill=white] (epi_note) at (22.5:6.7) {Quadratisch. Praktisch. Gut.\footnotemark\\Informationen\\???};

  \node [align=center] (prozedual) at (67.5:3.3) {prozeduale\\Informationen};
  \node [align=center,draw, fill=white] (proz_note) at (67.5:6.7) {Informationen \\zur Handlung};

  \node [align=center] (graphemisch) at (112.5:3.3) {graphemische\\Informationen};
  \node [align=center,draw, fill=white] (graph_note) at (112.5:6.7) {Informationen \\zur Schreibweise};

  \node [align=center] (morphologisch) at (157.5:3.3) {morphologische\\Informationen};
  \node [align=center,draw, fill=white] (morph_note) at (157.5:6.7) {morphologische \\Informationen};
  
  \node [align=center] (phonologisch) at (202.5:3.3) {phonologische\\Informationen};
  \node [align=center,draw, fill=white] (phon_note) at (202.5:6.7) {kwadratisch\\ipa\\lautschrift};

  \node [align=center] (syntaktisch) at (270:3.3) {syntaktische\\Informationen};
  \node [align=center,draw, fill=white] (syn_note) at (270:6.7) {vor dem Nomen\\Informationen};
  
  \node [align=center] (semantisch) at (337.5:3.3) {semantische\\Informationen};
  \node [align=center,draw, fill=white] (sem_note) at (337.5:6.7) {viereckig\\mit gleich langen Seiten\\Mathematik: in der zweiten Potenz\footnotemark};

  \node [align=center, draw] (lemma) at (0:7.5) {\textbf{Lemma}};
  \node [align=center, draw, fill=lightgray] (lexem) at (180:7.5) {\textbf{Lexem}};
  
  \node [rectangle, fill=white,draw] (quadratisch) at (0,0) {"quadratisch"};

\end{tikzpicture} 
\caption[test]{Modell eines Lexikoneintrages zum Wort "quadratisch"\footnotemark}

\end{figure}

\bigskip

\justifying

\blindtext[1]

\footnotetext[1]{\raggedright Werbeslogan der Schokoladenmarke Ritter Sport der Alfred Ritter GmbH \& Co. KG}
\footnotetext[2]{\raggedright Artikel des Wörterbuchs der deutschen Gegenwartssprache, elektronische Version, (1974) abgerufen unter https://www.dwds.de/wb/quadratisch}
\footnotetext[3]{\raggedright Modell nach Luger (2006) zitiert aus Reber K \& Schönauer-Schneider, W.(2018). Bausteine sprachheilpädagogischen Unterrichts. München: Reinhardt Verlag}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch Thanks! According to your username you speak my language. ;)

Comment: Und auch andere leute die deutsch reden -:)

Comment: Maybe this could help you getting started: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185728/47927 Ti*k*Z has only a ”color wheel” as polar gradient (which would be what you need), but you may be able to change the colors for this gradient.

Comment: Probably easier: use [this approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141378/47927) and draw a very thick arc that covers the segment exactly.

Comment: Last idea: fill the segment white, draw a thick arc over it that fully covers it and use [this approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5109/47927) to apply a gradient from gray to transparent to this path. Would this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,...,100}
    \fill[white!\x!lightgray]
        (0,0) -- (\fpeval{\x=0 ? 225 : 225+\x*90/101-0.02}:5)
        arc[start angle=\fpeval{\x=0 ? 225 : 225+\x*90/101-0.02},
        end angle=225+\x*90/101+90/101,
        radius=5] -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

without any package (except of course tikz)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x in {0,...,100}
        \fill[white!\x!lightgray]
        (0,0) -- (\ifnum \x=0 225 \else 225+\x*90/101-0.02 \fi:5)
        arc[start angle={\ifnum \x=0 225 \else 225+\x*90/101-0.02 \fi},
        end angle=225+\x*90/101+90/101,
        radius=5] -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn’t this even be possible without any additional packages? It essentially draws a lot of tiny segments coloured in different shades of gray, right? +1 anyways

Comment: @Jasper Habicht yes, see edit. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Best I could come up with:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}

%\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usetikzlibrary{mindmap, shadows, trees, shapes, through, positioning, backgrounds, fadings}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=15mm,
 top=20mm,
 right=15mm
 }

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-a}}
\lhead{XXX}
% \rfoot{Page \thepage}

\begin{document}

\hfill

\centering

{\huge\textbf{mentales Lexikon\\}}

\bigskip

\textbf{Übung zur Elaboration/Speicherung von Wörtern}\\\smallskip von XXX

\bigskip
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{tikzpicture}[framed, text centered]
  
  \coordinate (1) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (2) at (0,5);

  \fill[lightgray] (0,0) -- (90:5) arc (90:225:5) -- cycle; 
  
  %\fill[left color=lightgray, right color=white] (0,0) -- (225:5) arc (225:315:5) -- cycle; 

  %%% polar gradient fill %%%
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (315:0) -- (315:5) arc (315:225:5) -- cycle;
    \foreach \i in {1,...,100} {
      \draw[white!\i!lightgray, line width=4pt] 
        ({225+\i*(315-225)/100}:0) -- ({225+\i*(315-225)/100}:5);
    }
  \end{scope}
  %%% === %%%

  %fill=left!30!white

  \draw[black] (0:5)  -- (1);
  \draw[black] (45:5) -- (1);
  \draw[white] (90:5) -- (1);
  \draw[white] (135:5) -- (1);
  \draw[white] (180:5) -- (1);
  \draw[white] (225:5) -- (1);
  \draw[white] (270:5) -- (1);
  \draw[black] (315:5) -- (1);

  \node [draw, circle through=(2), very thick] at (1) {};

  \node [align=center] (episodisch) at (22.5:3.3) {episodische\\Informationen};
  \node [align=center,draw, fill=white] (epi_note) at (22.5:6.7) {Quadratisch. Praktisch. Gut.\footnotemark\\Informationen\\???};

  \node [align=center] (prozedual) at (67.5:3.3) {prozeduale\\Informationen};
  \node [align=center,draw, fill=white] (proz_note) at (67.5:6.7) {Informationen \\zur Handlung};

  \node [align=center] (graphemisch) at (112.5:3.3) {graphemische\\Informationen};
  \node [align=center,draw, fill=white] (graph_note) at (112.5:6.7) {Informationen \\zur Schreibweise};

  \node [align=center] (morphologisch) at (157.5:3.3) {morphologische\\Informationen};
  \node [align=center,draw, fill=white] (morph_note) at (157.5:6.7) {morphologische \\Informationen};
  
  \node [align=center] (phonologisch) at (202.5:3.3) {phonologische\\Informationen};
  \node [align=center,draw, fill=white] (phon_note) at (202.5:6.7) {kwadratisch\\ipa\\lautschrift};

  \node [align=center] (syntaktisch) at (270:3.3) {syntaktische\\Informationen};
  \node [align=center,draw, fill=white] (syn_note) at (270:6.7) {vor dem Nomen\\Informationen};
  
  \node [align=center] (semantisch) at (337.5:3.3) {semantische\\Informationen};
  \node [align=center,draw, fill=white] (sem_note) at (337.5:6.7) {viereckig\\mit gleich langen Seiten\\Mathematik: in der zweiten Potenz\footnotemark};

  \node [align=center, draw] (lemma) at (0:7.5) {\textbf{Lemma}};
  \node [align=center, draw, fill=lightgray] (lexem) at (180:7.5) {\textbf{Lexem}};
  
  \node [rectangle, fill=white,draw] (quadratisch) at (0,0) {"quadratisch"};

\end{tikzpicture} 
\caption[test]{Modell eines Lexikoneintrages zum Wort "quadratisch"\footnotemark}

\end{figure}

\bigskip

\justifying

\blindtext[1]

\footnotetext[1]{\raggedright Werbeslogan der Schokoladenmarke Ritter Sport der Alfred Ritter GmbH \& Co. KG}
\footnotetext[2]{\raggedright Artikel des Wörterbuchs der deutschen Gegenwartssprache, elektronische Version, (1974) abgerufen unter https://www.dwds.de/wb/quadratisch}
\footnotetext[3]{\raggedright Modell nach Luger (2006) zitiert aus Reber K \& Schönauer-Schneider, W.(2018). Bausteine sprachheilpädagogischen Unterrichts. München: Reinhardt Verlag}

\end{document}
```

The code essentially draw a lot of lines whose color shifts gradually from white to gray and whose angle gradually grows.

Shortcoming: the last line covers the other lines, which is quite visible.

[image]